# Prove a response was received from the particular Tor hidden service

Tags: signature, tls, non-repudiation

Consider a Tor hidden service. I want to retrieve the main page of such website in such a way that I can later prove to a **skeptical** third party that the website with this certificate (identified by the public key in the address) provided me with this exact HTML page.

Is this possible assuming the website does not install additional software and is just a normal website on the Darknet?

I know this cannot be done with SSL/TLS ( [How can you prove that a certain file was downloaded from a certain website?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/102615/how-can-you-prove-that-a-certain-file-was-downloaded-from-a-certain-website) ), how does the situation look within Tor?

Comment: I could not add the `tor` tag due to my low reputation as a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, except with some help from the website administrators, as suggested in the answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/102617/30665).

TOR gives us some browsing anonymization; so, it doesn't give you any non-repudiation. BTW, how could you demonstrate the chain of proxies used to download the website metadata was not emulated by you? We always can emulate a chain of proxies that is indistinguishable from a real one. So, any claim about their validity would be non-credible.